# Delete aligned memory from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, simd, eigen

(C++) I have memory aligned instances allocated on heap, then delete them in another thread. The codes look like this:

```
ALIGNED class Obj
{
public: ALIGNED_NEW_DELETE
...
};

Thread 1:
Obj *o = new Obj;  // overloaded new for aligned memory allocation
postTask(o);

Thread 2:
o->runTask();
delete o;  // overloaded delete for aligned memory deletion
// "delete" statement crashes
```

The delete statement in thread 2 will give an assertion error in Visual Studio 2013 (_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID).
Strangely, if i delete the object in the creation thread, everything runs fine.

Why does this happen? What's the solution?

**EDIT:**

@galop1n: Actually what i am currently using is Eigen's built-in new/delete operators EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW. I also tried my own operators, both failed.

For Eigen's operators, please look up its source yourself.

For my allocators:

```
void* operator new(size_t size){ return alignedMalloc(size, align); }
void operator delete(void* ptr) { alignedFree(ptr); } 
void* operator new[](size_t size) { return alignedMalloc(size, align); }
void operator delete[](void* ptr) { alignedFree(ptr); }  


void* alignedMalloc(size_t size, size_t align)
{
    char* base = (char*)malloc(size + align + sizeof(int));
    if (base == nullptr) 
           ASSERT(0, "memory allocation failed");
    char* unaligned = base + sizeof(int);
    char* aligned = unaligned + align - ((size_t)unaligned & (align - 1));
    ((int*)aligned)[-1] = (int)((size_t)aligned - (size_t)base);
    return aligned;
}

void alignedFree(const void* ptr) {
    int ofs = ((int*)ptr)[-1];
    free((char*)ptr - ofs);
}
```

And the ALIGNED macro is __declspec(align(16)). It crashes with or without the "ALIGNED" attribute.

Comment: Are you actually waiting for `o` to be constructed before calling `delete` on it?

Comment: @mfukar: yes, everything is perfectly synchronized. Actually if i create non-aligned instances, the delete statement runs fine.

Comment: @Defd Then it had to deal with your custom allocator.

Comment: Are you linking with the multithread versions of your tuntime libraries?

Comment: what are ALIGNED and ALIGNED_NEW_DELETE?  Those aren't C++ keywords.  If you #define them to something else, clue us in...

Comment: @Sean: Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)

Comment: I know you said "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)" I’m unfamiliar with Eigen, but just to clarify, is the version of the Eigen lib/dll you are linking to multi-threaded? Since you said you were calling their new and delete. If you’re not you’re in trouble. Another thing you could try is calling new/delete from the C-runtime since you know you are linking to multithreaded-dlls there (perhaps only to rule out that this is where the problem lies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is awkward, the problem is in Thread 2, The Obj* is casted into a base class' pointer Task*, and for the utter stupidity: ~Task() is not virtual:

```
class Task 
{
public:
  ~Task();  // <-- not virtual, therefore it crashes
  ...
}

ALIGNED class Obj : public Task 
{ ... }
```

Should have discovered this problem much much earlier. Because, as in my description of the problem, i said it myself it gives an assertion error: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID, this is a visual studio debug lib's stuff for the default delete operator, which means it didn't even run into my overloaded delete operator, which ultimately means I missed a "virtual".

It's my bad that i even forgot to add the class inheritance to the question.

Sometimes, i can be stuck at a problem for hours or even days. But after i posted the issue online, i can immediately find the answer. Dunno if any of you have similar problems before; perhaps i've put too much stress onto myself.

Still, thanks you, Internet.

Comment: It's always like this: once I hit a hard problem not able to solve myself for hours, I try to formulate the issue in a comprehensive question for posting on SO - just to realize that there is actually an _obvious_ and often simple solution to this problem ;)

Comment: no one could have figured this out because you omitted the most important detail.... that you actually cast a pointer in the second thread before calling delete.  This is what is called an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  The problem has nothing to do with threading, but your title is "delete aligned memory from another thread".

Comment: @thang: true. i decide to keep the question as it is to show how important details can be ignored by askers. Same issues happen in all industries, some great discovery even rooted from these seemingly unimportant traits, mostly notable in math and physics. For all ppl reading this question, please learn from my mistake.